# undefined drupal_add_js function inside themename_preprocess_page

Tags: theming

I wanted to use javascript to delete an option from the list of options in case the user is not an administrator and I searched and found this code inside a post and I used it inside the project's themes->mythemename->mythemename.theme file, but that didn't work and I have several problems I want to know how to solve, as I searched a lot I did not find a solution

```
function mythemename_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {
    if (!in_array("administrator", \Drupal::currentUser()->roles) {
        if (isset($variables['node']->type) && !empty($variables['node']->type) && (strpos($variables['node']->type, 'proxy_request') !== false)) {
            drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mythemename') . '/js/datcbaseauth.js');
        }
    }
}
```

The first problem is that I can't get the data of the current user, as I am always reported that it is the second parameter of the in_array function is null.

The second problem is that I am telling that the second parameter of the strpos function is an object and not just a string even though the example in the post was treating it as just a string.

The third and final problem is that I am saying that function drupal_add_js and function drupal_get_path are undefined.

I searched for a long time, but I did not find a solution to these 3 problems, even the topics they may mentioned in it are not complete, for example, do not report how to use the drupal_add_js function inside the .theme file what is the prerequisite or even within Drupal's documentation itself, there is no data on the variable &$variables will tell about its content, the nature of each part, etc except that it is an associative array

Answer (score 1):

- First problem to get current user roles use this

  \Drupal::currentUser()->getRoles();
- Second problem: `$variables['node']->type` is an array so use `$variables['node']->bundle()` to get type instead:
- The third **drupal_add_js** not supported anymore in Drupal 8 use library and attached so try something like the following

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (in_array("administrator", \Drupal::currentUser()->getRoles())) {
    if ($variables['node']->bundle() && (strpos($variables['node']->bundle(), 'proxy_request') !== FALSE)) {
      $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'THEME/custom-library';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I got this error after editing "Error: call to a member function bundle or null in gasfv1_preprocess_page()" knowing that the name gasfv1 is the name of the custom theme. This is my new code now function -> function gasfv1_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {
    if (!in_array("administrator", \Drupal::currentUser()->getRoles()) {
        if ($variables['node']->bundle() && (strpos($variables['node']->bundle(), 'proxy_request') !== false)) {
            $variables['#attached']['library'][] ='gasfv1/js/datcbaseauth.js';
        }
    }
}

Comment: Is my question that difficult?

Comment: if you get the error add the the condition *isset($variables['node'])* in the if statement!

Comment: The problem is not in the condition. The problem is that it means that there is no item called a node inside the variable $variables and I want to know if the machine name of the content type being rendered contains a certain pattern, i.e., proxy_request, so that I can insert my javascript file for those pages, which are content type

Comment: Normally the **$variables['node']** contain node information if you are in node page, for example you have a content type called  *proxy_request* and your current page is node of type *proxy_request you will find the informations inside node key